# Table Row CSS Background Color Won't Change

Tags: css

I have the following CSS:

```
.tableStatic tbody tr { border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7; }
.tableStatic tbody tr:nth-child(even) { background-color:#f5f5f5; }
```

I want to change the background of certain "holiday" rows as follows

```
.tableStatic tbody tr { border-top: 1px solid #e7e7e7; }
.tableStatic tbody tr:nth-child(even) { background-color:#f5f5f5; }
.tableStatic tbody tr .holiday {background-color: #778899;}
```

How ever it doesn't work. The background color is changed but it is using #f5f5f5 instead of #778899

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space there:

```
.tableStatic tbody tr .holiday {background-color: #778899;}
```

Remove it and it should work.

```
.tableStatic tbody tr.holiday {background-color: #778899;}
```

Comment: Depending on the styles would `.tableStatic tr.holiday` work as well?

Comment: @Anagio: You would have to remove `tbody` from the other two rules as well, so you don't run into specificity mix-ups.

Comment: @Anagio: Exactly - and the problem with that is you don't really want the table header row(s) to be striped.

Answer (score 1):

Is there an element in the table row with a class 'holiday'? Because that's what your last CSS rule does.

If you want to style the actual table rows which have a class of 'holiday' you must simply remove one space.

```
.tableStatic tbody tr.holiday {background-color: #778899;}
```

Notice there is no space between 'tr' and '.holiday'

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
.tableStatic tbody tr .holiday {background-color: #778899 !important;}
```

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem, and advocating `!important` without particular reason is bad practice.